# How do I Add another SHA-1 to google or use Keystore

Tags: java, android-studio, keystore, google-signin, android-keystore

My friend and I are trying to make application that has social sign in feature.

I have added Facebook Sign In with my computer and both of our hash keys are put into Facebook account.

However, for Google Sign In, my friend put his SHA1 in Google configuration step, and got configuration json file which is added to our app.

Right now, I cannot use Google Sign In feature with my keystore. I'll have to copy my friend's keystore and replace it with ~/.android/debug.keystore.

But if I replace it, then Facebook Sign In wouldn't work.

Is there a way to add my SHA1 to Google my app without making new app?

Comment: Does this help? http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html